# Reading the content of the uploaded file in Struts2

Tags: java, struts2

How can I read the content of an uploaded file in the `execute()` method of the `Action` class? I am able to upload the file on the server but do not know how to read the content of that file.

Do we have to first save it on the server? Or can we read it directly?

Comment: You say you can upload the file to the server... does this mean the file is already on the server? Do you mean you've provided an action that lets a user upload content or there is a folder on the server where you've placed a file and want to read it?

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1: Create a servlet**

I recommend you utilize apache commons [file upload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html). This link has examples on how to process the uploaded file (writing it to a disk or reading it in memory if the file size is small enough) using [FileItem](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/apidocs/org/apache/commons/fileupload/FileItem.html). Another relevant example can be found [here](http://www.servletworld.com/servlet-tutorials/servlet-file-upload-example.html).

**Option 2: using the struts `s:file` tag**

As @BalusC mentioned in the comments below struts has a built in file upload process using [s:file](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/file-upload.html) tag library and a tutorial of using it is provided [here](http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-file-upload-example/). Essentially the file gets uploaded to a temporary directory. However, you can override that by setting a value for the `struts.multipart.saveDir` property in the `default.properties` file. This link also mentions using Apache [FileUtils](http://commons.apache.org/io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html) to process the uploaded file afterwards which by the way is a very handy library for any File I/O work.

Comment: I don't do Struts2, but I'd imagine that a bit MVC framework has builtin facilities for this, for sure if it's an Apache framework. I peeked a bit round on mkyong.com and I found this: http://www.mkyong.com/struts2/struts-2-file-upload-example/ Bringing in Apache Commons FileUpload is a bit overkill.

Comment: @BalusC thanks - that's a good link on the file upload process using `s:file` tag and apache `FileUtils` class. Although the link does not explicitly explain how to process the file but I think that part should be trivial. Do you mind posting it as an answer? I can delete my post since it seems the OP ought to be using struts provided file upload procedure.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if that's helpful and I am not a fan of answers containing just a link :)

Comment: @BalusC - As you wish! Anyway, I modified my answer to include both options and hints on how to upload & process the file. Hope this helps the OP :)

Answer (score 3):

http://java.dzone.com/articles/struts2-tutorial-part-67 Here he explains how to make a very clear and detailed upload

Comment: I glad to hear that. Please mark my post as the answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's the standard way that provides Struts2, with an example:

http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/file-upload.html

It's quite simple and elegant (no need to mess with `servletRequest.getRealPath("/")` as ther other example linked by hoss).

By using the `<s:file>` tag (and the appropiate interceptor), Struts2 makes all the dirty work and gives you the (temporary) uploaded file as a  `File` field in the action; you can open it or move, or whatever, as you do with any file.