# unable to find  image file after loading it on the server in struts2

Tags: file-upload, struts2

```
  <s:form action="resultAction" namespace="/" 
    method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <s:file name="fileUpload" label="Select a File to upload" size="40" />

    <s:submit value="submit" name="submit" />

  </s:form>

   public String execute() {
    try {

        String filePath = servletRequest.getRealPath("/");
        System.out.println("Server path:" + filePath);
        File fileToCreate = new File(filePath, this.userImageFileName);

        FileUtils.copyFile(this.userImage, fileToCreate);


    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        addActionError(e.getMessage());

        return INPUT;
    }
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

my file is getting previewed.it is stored in location C:\Users\Nirmala.netbeans\6.8\GlassFish_v3\generated\jsp\strutsfileupload\uploa‌​d_4877f322_130a84c40c4__7fd1_00000001.tmp but i am unable to find it in my directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Was answered already here: [Reading the content of the uploaded file in Struts2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6350798/reading-the-content-of-the-uploaded-file-in-struts2/6362811#6362811)

Comment: k i have read the answer....the example http://java.dzone.com/articles/struts2-tutorial-part-67 is running but my file is getting previewed.it is stored in location  C:\Users\Nirmala\.netbeans\6.8\GlassFish_v3\generated\jsp\strutsfileupload\upload_4877f322_130a84c40c4__7fd1_00000001.tmp but i am unable to find it in my directory

Comment: Try to search in \Struts2FileUpload\build\web\

Comment: yes i got it.what to do if i want to save it in another directory

Comment: In your Action change the folder path:

String filePath = servletRequest.getRealPath("/") + "folder/you/want/";

Comment: i am  adding C:\\Users\\Nirmala\\Desktop\\HCL ,it is giving error

Comment: String filePath="C:\\Users\\Nirmala\\Desktop\\HCL" ,file is getting uploaded but the location of file is C:\Users\Nirmala\.netbeans\6.8\GlassFish_v3\generated\jsp\strutsfileupload\uploa‌​d_4877f322_130a84c40c4__7fd1_00000001.tmp getting displayed

Comment: Hey, change your filePath like this: String filePath = servletRequest.getRealPath("/") + "folder/you/want/"; Application did not understang what this means "C:\\Users\\Nirmala\\Desktop\\HCL". The servletRequest.getRealPath("/") means the root of your WebApplication

Comment: Because HCl is on your Desktop, not in your root folder of your WebApplication

Comment: i have placed hcl under web pages of netbeans project.then also image is not coming

Comment: servletRequest.getRealPath("/") +"HCL/" pay attention at backslash

Comment: k images is getting saved in build/web/images but it is not showing in my netbeans ide under images folder

Comment: Look in Files tab, under your project.

Comment: yes i got it,thks.if i want to save the path in database C:\Users\Nirmala\.netbeans\6.8\GlassFish_v3\generated\jsp\strutsfileupload\uploa‌​d_4877f322_130a84c40c4__7fd1_00000001.tmp should be saved

Comment: In database you need to save only image name. But in JSP to show it, just put: <img src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/HCL/yourimage.jpg" />

Comment: then i should use hibernate for that